# Manim Community v0.7.0 - ValueError: Your installation does not support converting .dvi files to SVG

Tags: manim

I have the following simple code in a file called latex.py:

```
from manim import *

class Formula(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        formula_text=Tex(r"cucumber").scale(2)
        self.add(formula_text)
```

I run it using the below command:

**manim -p -ql latex.py Formula**

And I get the following error:

*ValueError: Your installation does not support converting .dvi files to SVG. Consider updating dvisvgm to at least version 2.4. If this does not solve the problem, please refer to our troubleshooting guide at:
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/troubleshooting.html*

I have Manim Community v0.7.0 installed.
My dvisvgm version is 2.11.1.

I have followed all the directions in the link above and can confirm that **dvisvgm -h** and **dvisvgm -l** return values as expected. Moreover, if I try to use **dvisvgm** command on it's own (by giving it a random .dvi file) - it works fine.

I only get this problem when using Tex or MathTex mobjects (Text mobject works fine).

Any suggestion what else I could do to try to get to the bottom of it??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to reinstall LaTeX!